# How to modify Row Height in Serviice Cloud Console view

Tags: service-cloud-console, servicecloud, winter16, custom-service-console

I'm using ServiceCloud - Which recently (Winter16) had a major overhaul in terms of GUI. After the winter 16 GUI Update, the Service Cloud Case Console view, showing case records takes up much more space. Anyy ideas on how to modify the Case List View (Record Row Height)?

Before:
[image: Before]
After:
[image]

Comment: It is the styles and CSS that is being used by default in Lightning. I do not think you can override default css without recreating the page from scratch.....Lets let someone confirm this though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists an option to return to the previous list view style. If you modify your console app under Setup->Create->Apps there is a checkbox called 'Responsive Lists'. Unchecking this box will return that console app to the previous style of list view.

Comment: Well this is not quite a solution - though it is an acceptable workaround.

Answer (score 0):

One other workaround might include altering the CSS externally, i.e - via a Goole Chrome Extension. Obviously this is not ideal, but a workaround though.